# PHPExcel for loop timeout

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

I have this code where I want to set from 3 to 333 to have a certain row height at every 30 interval, meaning at row 3, 33, 63, 93 up till 333:

```
for ($i=3; $i<340; $i+30){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($i)->setRowHeight(57);
}
```

But when I click on controller actionGenerate(), it doesn't generate and timeouts me after 30 seconds. Can I know why isn't it generating?

If I were to use the manual way, as in doing line by line, PLUS having so many different kinds of settings, I'd be exhausted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PHP` limits the execution time of any script. The default time is 30 seconds.
Your script probably takes longer than 30 seconds to execute.

Set your `set_time_limit` to `0`.
This will set it to unlimited.

like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
for ($i=3; $i<340; $i+=30){ // <--- here was your problem
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($i)->setRowHeight(57);
}
```

And try again.

Info about `set_time_limit` in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

-- edit--

The problem was in the `for` loop.

`$i + 30` adds `30` to `$i` but it does not assign it.
It should be `$i +=30`

Comment: It doesn't timeout, but it takes forever to load. Is there something wrong somewhere in the code?

Comment: Yes, it should be `$i+=30` it now adds `30` to `i` but it doesn't assign it.

Comment: @Yeen np, glad I could help.